# Hibernate envers, liquibase and postgres. entity_aud is not found

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase, hibernate-envers

I have a spring boot v2.7.1 project running with liquibase and hibernate.
When i execute the command gradle diffChangeLog liquibase is generating tables with _AUD suffix and then hibernate is blowing an error

> ERROR: relation "comment_aud" does not exist.

here are the relative information from my configuration files:
build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}" #2.7.1
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "jacoco"
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'org.liquibase.gradle'
depedencies {
    implementation "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.1.1'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.8.0'
    liquibaseRuntime 'info.picocli:picocli:4.6.3'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:4.13.0'
    liquibaseRuntime "org.postgresql:postgresql"
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
}
liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            driver 'org.postgresql.Driver'
            url 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database'
            username 'admin'
            password 'admin'
            changeLogFile "src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/" + new Date().format("yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss") + "-changelog.xml"
            referenceUrl 'hibernate:spring:mypackagedir.entity' +
                    '?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect' +
                    '&implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy' +
                    '&?physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy'
            defaultSchemaName ""
            classpath "build/classes/java/main"
            logLevel "debug"
        }
    }

    runList = 'main'
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    password: ${database.password}
    url: ${database.host}
    username: ${database.username}
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      org:
        hibernate:
          envers:
            global_with_modified_flag: true
            store_data_at_delete: true
            audit_table_suffix: _aud
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
    show-sql: true
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
```

part of the generated changelog after i do diffChangeLog

```
...
<createTable tableName="comment_AUD">
    <column name="REV" type="INTEGER">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="comment_AUDPK"/>
            </column>
    <column name="REVTYPE" type="SMALLINT"/>
...
```

as you can see liquibase is generating the audit table with _AUD although i set it to _aud in hibernate properties

i tried the following:

- adding and removing all or one of naming_strategies in build.gradle file

```
&implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy&?physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

- adding removing naming strategies in application.yml properties:

```
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

- changing the suffix to `audit_table_suffix:_AUD`

but nothing helps! i am running in circles now and can't find a solution for this. can someone tell me how to fix this please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just want to make sure, you do understand that you have to run this liquibase changelog against the database that your application is connecting with to actually create these table, right? I don't know how Spring runs these changelogs, but it seems to me that it simply doesn't them.

Comment: Are you seeing that table actually generated in the database? If so, in the table is the _aud in caps or lower case in the table? Anything in Postgres that is not quoted automatically converts to lowercase. This might be a bug. If you comment out the `audit_table_suffix: _aud` and run diffChangeLog, does it work? Just curious to see if that configuration still throws an error, maybe with different text.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov of course. i wont get caps if i dont run liquibase. btw spring has a plugin for liquibase so something like `grade diffChangeLog` would work.

Comment: @tabbyfoo yes i can see the tables added are with _AUD caps. i tried to remove the suffix and it didnt help. actually i added it as a try to fix this.

Comment: the solution i applied for the moment is @AuditTable("comment_aud")
this annotation is used on the entity class it self